# Is there a Page Snooze add-on for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, reminder

I'm really taken by the Google Chrome extension "[Page Snooze](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-snooze)", which lets you close a tab and schedule it to reappear in say a week.

Is there any add-on/extension like Page Snooze for Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TabAlarm](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tabalarm/) seems to let you shedule a tab to appear at a certain time, and you can then close the tab yourself.

I also found an extension called [SnoozeTabs](https://people.mozilla.org/~bwinton/snoozetabs/) which seems pretty similar to Page Snooze.

[image]

Comment: Neither of these links work any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tab Snooze - [website snapshot from December 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20141224171213/http://www.tabsnooze.com/), it's currently only supported on Google Chrome,
but a Safari and Firefox port is coming out in 2 months.

Edit: This does not exist any more, and the home page seems to redirect to random spam/malware pages.